# como puedo hacer esto en react

Tags: reactjs

como puedo hacer esto en react

**var slider = document.querySelector(".slier-prin");**

**slider.innerHTML += slider.innerHTML**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! o sea.. en react eso es simplemente cambiar la propiedad que contiene ese elemento... no entiendo la pregunta...

Comment: Averigua el uso del [`useState`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 0):

Pues debes explicar mejor lo que quieres hacer para darte una mejor respuesta, sin embargo esto te puede ayudar, la función hacerEstoEnReact() busca el elemento .slier-prin y le asigna lo que ya tenia mas lo que tiene, ahora existen dos formas de ejecutarlo una es por medio de un boton haciendo uso de un evento onClick y la otra es ejecutarlo al renderizar por medio del hook useEffect

```
import { useEffect} from 'react'

export default function Ejemplo(){

    useEffect(() =>{
        hacerEstoEnReact();
    });

    function hacerEstoEnReact(){
        let slider = document.querySelector('.slier-prin');
        slider.innerHtml += slider.value;
    };

    return(
      <>
          <button onClick={hacerEstoEnReact}>Ejecutar función</button>
      </>
 )
}
```